# How to change the text highlighting color in Okular?

Tags: colors, pdf-reader, highlighting, annotations, okular

How can you quickly switch between text highlighting colors for the "Review" tools in the Okular PDF-reader? For example when browsing through a PDF file and wanting to color different topics differently?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way of doing it is creating different highlighters with different colors. They can be accessed via the number keys. 
In order to get to the menu, right-click on one of the annotation tools.

[image: Annotation toolbar with differently colored highlighting pens]

Comment: You may need to hit "F6" in order for the annotations to show up.  Then, right click any of the annotations to edit them, and change them to a highlighter of desired color.